# ZXing.BarcodeReader code not decode barcode

Tags: zxing.net

This barcode:

[image: Sample Barcode]

Will not decode.  What is wrong with that image that it will not decode.

```
string barcodePng = "tmp.png";
reader = new BarcodeReader();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);
reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
using (var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(barcodePng))
{
    var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
    if (result != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("barcode did not decode");
    }
}
```

This one is different from other thousands of other images that did decode in that I had to repair the original .tif file that it was cut from because it was damaged.  I repaired it by converting it to .pdf and back to .tif.

Comment: Some bars merged due to low resolution/blurring.

Comment: I assume this is Code 39; compare your image to the [valid barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2qpV.png) for the same data.

Comment: I voted you up for providing an image of a valid one.  I will try repairing image a different way that will not blur the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is wrong with that image that it will not decode.

It will not decode because some bars have merged and/or changed their widths due to low resolution and blurring.

Assuming the symbology is [Code 39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39), the valid barcode looks like this:

[image]

Comment: To fix the image I converted to .pdf with a different print option.  I turned off the "sharpen" option on the print driver.